# Javascript scoping variables theory

Tags: javascript, html, scope

I have two example pages that are behaving differently and I would like to know why. To me they seem consistent with each other based one what I have gathered about scoping in javascript.

1.html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function demofunction(x, y) {
    z=x+y;
  }
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>4-6.htm</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bad Scoping</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    demofunction(3, 2);
    alert(z);
    var z;
    alert(z);
    //]]>
    </script>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>

</html>
```

In this example, demofunction runs and sets the global variable z to 5. alert runs and since there is no z in scope it grabs the global scope and finds a z which is equal to 5, it alerts that. then a new local variable named z is defined. the second alert can see that local variable, but since it is undefined, it choses the global one and alerts 5 again.

2.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bad Scoping</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  first = 6;
  document.writeln('<p>first is ' + first + "</p>");

  function letsSee() {
    alert(first);
    var first;
    first = 4;
  }
  letsSee();
  document.writeln('<p>but now first is ' + first + "</p>");

  //]]>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

global first gets set to 6. letsSee() runs and the alert (if consistent) should see no local variable named first so it should alert the global variable 6. then a local first is defined, which is then set to 4. letsSee() exists and the last print prints the global first and shows 6 again.

this does NOT happen though. what happens is that it shows 6, alert has undefined, and shows 6. my question is directed to why does it alert undefined rather than 6? if i comment the line inside letsSee for `var first;` i then see that it alerts 6 and then display's 4. this makes sense to me. but why does having that var first after the alert make a difference to what the alert call sees as the value? esp when it didn't make a difference in 1.html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`var` and `function` declarations are *hoisted* before any code is executed.

```
function letsSee() {
  alert(first);
  var first;
  first = 4;
}
```

behaves like

```
function letsSee() {
  var first = undefined;
  alert(first);
  first = 4;
}
```

As an easier to understand example, you can call functions before they are declared:

```
foo();  // works!
function foo() { ... }
```

This is because the `function` declaration is looked at first and hoisted, you can call it anywhere regardless of when/where in the code you declare it. The same happens with variables declared using `var`. The variable itself (the *name*) is hoisted. Writing `var foo;` *anywhere* within a given scope will make any higher-scoped variable `foo` unaccessible within that scope.

```
var foo = 'foo';

function () {
    alert(foo);        // All of these can't see the higher-scoped
    doSomething(foo);  // foo = 'foo' variable, because the
    return foo;        // local foo has already been hoisted.

    var foo;  // masks the higher-scoped foo within the entire scope,
              // even if it doesn't appear to be executed
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `The same happens with variables declared using var.`. I'm probably doing it wrong, but it [didn't work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/UK9wu/).

Comment: @alex Look at my example again. The "name" of the variable is hoisted, but the value assignment will still happen where you wrote it.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, my brain isn't working too well this afternoon. If a variable name is hoisted, will it lead to any potential issues (can't think of any right now - aren't all non assigned variables `undefined` in PHP)?

Comment: @alex It's only an issue if you expect it to work differently than it does. :)

Comment: Do note the difference that deceze has mentioned regarding Function and Variable hoisting. function a(){ 
function a(){ 
//foo1(); this will not work as foo1 is a variable with function value
foo2();
var foo1= function(){
        alert(a);
    }
function foo2(){
        alert(a);
    }
var a = "hi"
foo1();
foo2();
};
a();

Comment: thanks! the "hoisting" explanation really improves my understanding of what is going on!

Answer (score 3):

There are two things that are throwing you off

**1.** your assumption that the `<script>...</script>` block has its own scope like a function has scope.  The truth is that all `<script>` blocks exist in the same global scope.

**2.** you've also assumed that the `var` declaration occurs in the order in which it appears in the code.  The truth is that all `var`s in a given scope are executed at the *beginning* of that scope. (-edit- just to clarify: the var *declaration* happens at the beginning of the scope, but any assignment operation remains at its original spot in the code.  The value of a variable that has been declared, but not yet had a value assigned is `undefined`).

So... in your first example, `var z` is actually declaring `z` in the *global* scope, then the call to `demofunction()` operates on that global `z`, and both alerts run against the *same* global `z`.

Whereas, in your second example, `first` is initially set in the global scope, then declared again within the function's *local* scope.  In the function, the alert and the assignment both operate on the *local* variable. Outside the function the `writeln()`s operate on the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because function declarations are hoisted in JavaScript - i.e. that function runs up the top, where that variable you are trying to access is not defined.