# What is the mean of this? Engine bug or what?

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, var

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript scoping variables theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405749/javascript-scoping-variables-theory)

Hi all,

I want to ask something stranger. Here is the code.

```
var a = "defined";
function f() {
   alert(a);
   var a = 5;
}
f();
```

alerts "undefined"

Can anyone explain that why I am getting "undefined".

Fatih..

Comment: Essentially exact duplicate of [Javascript scoping variables theory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405749/javascript-scoping-variables-theory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called ***JavaScript Hoisting*** i suppose. Check out this video to learn more about it and solution to it:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/

To make it work, you will have to remove the `var` keyword form variable `a`:

```
var a = "defined";
function f() {
   alert(a);
   a = 5;
}
f();
```

So basically, it is a variable scope issue. The act of removing `var` keyword makes a variable globally available. Hence, there is no error raised this time.

Comment: However, removing `var` may also not do what you want, because now you are messing with the global variable. (It is less surprising though).

Comment: Interesting. This is something I didn't know, and I'm surprised it hasn't caught me out yet. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

In the function you get a new scope.

The `var a` in the function declares a local variable `a`, which masks the global one.

The assignment to `a` takes place later (after the alert), so until then `a` is undefined.

The confusing part is that it does not matter if you have the `var a` declaration on top or anywhere else in the function (can even be inside an if). The effect is the same: It declares a variable for that scope (effective even for code that is located before the declaration). That is why jslint recommends to declare all local variables on top.